# What's the purpose of QString?

Tags: c++, string, qt, std

I'm a newcomer to C++ and Qt. I've been messing around with Qt Creator for a few days, and what really struck me was how the GUI components only accepted a `const QString&` rather than a `string` or an `std::wstring`. To stay consistent with this, I've been trying to accept and return `QString` from most of my function calls, however I find myself converting to and from `std::string` a lot to use most of the standard library facilities.

My question here is, what's the purpose of `QString` if `std::string` is part of the standard library? I guess this would be beneficial to someone who was already using Qt and didn't want another dependency on `#include <string>`, but to be honest you'll need `std::string` if you want to do anything useful with your application. (This especially goes for `QChar`, since `char` is a builtin.)

Can someone explain to me why this is not reinventing the wheel and how this helps being cross-platform?

Comment: One reason would be that Qt uses the UTF-8 text format, and std::string is not UTF-8 aware.  (That is, you can store a UTF-8 string inside a std::string, but if you try to iterate over the string using std::string's iterator, you will be iterating over bytes, not over characters, which is not usually what you want)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner True, but we already have `std::wstring` and `wchar_t` (UTF-16, I believe) so I don't think this alone justifies creating a whole new string class.

Comment: Utf-16 and utf-8 are different encodings.  Utf-8 is capable of things that utf-16 cant do.

Comment: `std::string` is one of these things that stop making any sense outside of a classroom. Utterly non-portable, and useless if you want to do anything besides simply holding strings. `std::string` is a kind of a bastard child of the C++ standardization effort. Just as other C++ containers are wonderfully usable, so is the string useless. It makes sense if you're porting from C's `strxxx` functions, and that's about it.

Comment: Kuba when you say non-portable do you mean non-portable across computer architectures, or non-portable for use with different human languages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question here is, what's the purpose of `QString` if `std::string` is part of the standard library?

Reasons that I can think of:

1. `QString` has been part of the Qt library way before `std::string` came to life.
2. Its interface includes a lot of Qt specific classes. Hence, the usage of `QString` cannot be easily replaced by `std::string`.
3. Its interface is a lot richer than `std::string`.

Comment: Ah, so basically for compat / usability reasons. I'm assuming the same reasons for `QChar` as well? `char` has been around probably since the advent of the language.

Comment: QChar is a lot more that char.

Comment: @JamesKo Qt has a strong focus on portability and the Qt recommended version of char is qint8. As to QChar "The QChar class provides a 16-bit Unicode character" it's not even the same thing as char.

Comment: @mikag That's inaccurate. A `QChar` represents a Unicode code unit, *not* a code point! The phrase "16 bit Unicode character" is nonsense, since in Unicode terms, a character has a very specific meaning to which a "16 bit" modifier doesn't apply.

Comment: @KubaOber interesting. I probably should have added the source ref but I couldn't figure out the correct link format in  comments. Mea Culpa. But that quote is straight from the Qt QChar docs...

Comment: @mikag You'd be more than welcome to submit a documentation update to fix that :)

Answer (score 6):

One advantage of `QString` over `std::string` is that it's easier to write platform-independent code.  For Unicode support most platforms use UTF-8 encoding, whereas Windows uses UTF-16 encoding.

Adding to the confusion, while a `char` is the same size on all platforms `wchar_t` is not.  So the size of a character in `std::wstring` will vary from platform to platform.

`QString` eliminates this confusion by using UTF-16 encoding on all platforms.  If you need to interact with platform-specific code, `QString` provides helper methods to convert to and from UTF-8, UTF-32, native `std` types, etc.