# Difference between QString and std::string

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Whats the difference between QString and std:: string 
and why can't I say:

```
    QString name;
    std::string name1;
    name = name1;
```

although both are strings

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Related: [What's the purpose of QString?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601668/whats-the-purpose-of-qstring)

Comment: _"...although both are strings..."_  You know that, I now that, the compiler does not.  For the compiler, it's the same as saying `int x = 0; std::string s; s = x;`  It just doesn't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QString` is Qt frameworks's own implementation of Strings library whereas `std::string` is the implementation of Strings which comes bundled with rest of the other C/C++ libraries such as `iostream`, stdio etc.
You can read up on `QString` further [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html)

Answer (score 7):

How would the compiler deduce that "both are strings" and how to convert one into another?

While both this classes represent strings, they are still *different, unrelated classes*. They cannot be converted from one to another unless explicitly stated (like appropriate conversion operators or constructors), much like you cannot use simple assignment to convert `std::vector<int>` to `std::list<int>`.

`QString` has a static method `fromStdString` which can work for you:

```
name = QString.fromStdString(name1);
```

Notice that it expectes that `std::string` contains utf-8 data.

Answer (score 7):

Unlike C#, Java and other languages, there is **no native string type in the C++ language**. When you type string literals like `"abc"` in source code, the compiler will convert them into an array of **char** type with a zero-value element at the end (forming the well-known *'zero-terminated string'* values);

To make life easier for developers, C++ includes a standard library class for strings (std::string), but this is simply one implementation for handling zero-terminated character arrays. QString is another implementation. And there are, of course, hundreds more written by developers to suit their own needs.

So the reason you can't directly assign from one to the other is that they are completely different types - the compiler doesn't know that both are used for manipulating strings - it just treats them as separate, incompatible classes.

Comment: `String` is not a native type in Java. The specification does not use the expression "native type" anyway. There are "primitive types" and "reference types"; `String` belongs to the latter category. However, it's true that special treatment of literals and operator overloading makes the type special.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Your argument is the same for C#, where *string* is simply a forced alias to the System.String reference type. The point was simply to indicate that other languages make special effort to support strings as their own type, whereas C/C++ turns them into arrays.

Comment: I don't agree with this interpretation. To me, `std::string` is part of the *standard* library and thus part of the C++ *language* exactly like its Java or C# counterparts (if you don't count free-standing implementations). Whether you `import java.lang.String` or `#include <string>` does not matter. One could as well write their own `char[]`-based custom string class in Java or C#; it's just that the uselessness of such a class would be more *apparent* in those languages.

Comment: @ChristianHackl that's fine. My argument would be that "abc" is a `char[]` in C++ and a `String` type in both C# and Java. Yep, you could write your own `char[]`-based classes for C# and Java, but you would have to convert literals from a String type first! Anyway, I think we are simply looking at the same idea from different angles.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that they are, well, different. Unless the designers of `QString` provided an assignment operator taking a `const std::string &` argument, and they didn't do that.

To get a `QString` from `std::string`, you need to use `QString::fromStdString`, and the conversion is done assuming that `std::string` was UTF-8-encoded. You can't blindly assume that it's a valid assumption: you must understand where does your `std::string` come from and what encoding it's in.

---

You can't assign one to the other because it's not a cheap operation, and you'd need to provide some information about, at least, what is the encoding used in the `std::string`. Recall that `QString` stores UTF-16 Unicode code units. It doesn't store Unicode characters directly, and a `QChar` is really a misnomer: it's not a character, but a UTF-16 code unit (*not* code point). Sometimes, when a character happens to have a single-unit UTF-16 encoding, things work out "nicely", but that's but a coincidence.

`std::string` is worse: it knows nothing about its encoding, it's simply a vector of some characters. It makes it almost useless in many applications where you actually care what those characters mean.